# Unit Test in .NET not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new to unit test scenarios. Really new.

I tried with few examples and it worked.
But, now I want to try this code:

O/P: the output i get is actual : 0 and expected : 75.
Here, my actual code is with dummy data. But if i input values, it works.
What things, are going wrong ?

Could anyone tell me please.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the test? It looks like you are never adding items to the scannedItems dictionary, which means totalPrice is 0.

Comment: Break your methods into smaller parts (more methods) and write tests for those. For example, the 1st test should be assertions against getTotalPrice.  _scannedItems.Count > 0 can be a separate method.  Convert to percent can be a separate method, (discountPercent * totalPrice) / 100)... and so on. Eventually the bug becomes obvious because the unit tests will tell you.

Comment: Cant i add only in test case, to see if it works ? I dont want to add it in the real program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing forces you to think about your code differently, as you're discovering now. With no tests, it seems to make sense to have a private dictionary of scanned items instantiated by the same class that performs calculations on that collection. Now, it's apparent that this coupling makes it harder to reason about what you class does.

The solution is to use dependency injection. Redefine the class under test to take a scanned items dictionary as a constructor parameter.

```
public class Register
{
    private Dictionary<Int, Item> _scannedItems;

    public Register(Dictionary<Int, Item> scannedItems)
    {
        _scannedItems = scannedItems;
    }

    // ... the rest as usual
}
```

Now you can set up your scanned items dictionary in different ways for each test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void applyDiscountByPercentTest()
{
    var scannedItems = new Dictionary<Int, Items>() {
        /* init with items */
    };
    Register target = new Register(scannedItems);
    double discountPercent = 25;
    double expected = 75;

    actual = target.applyDiscountByPercent(discountPercent);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
}
```

Comment: It's basically impossible to do unit testing without dependency injection; yours is the only answer that mentioned it

Answer (score 1):

GetTotalPrice() is returning 0, because you haven't got anything in your _scannedItems list. I assume that you want to work out the discount applicable to the initialized actual value, but the code you're testing isn't using that, it's using scannedItems, which your unit test doesn't populate with anything.

You'd need a public method for adding items to the list, and then your unit test should call that to add items to the list and work out the discount applicable on the total.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any items to the `_scannedItems` collection so inside the function it always returns 0 as `getTotalPrice()` is always 0.

Comment: Cant i add only in test case, to see if it works ? I dont want to add it in the real program.

Comment: You didn't show more of your class so I cannot say, but I assume you have some method that fills the `_scannedItems` collection?

Comment: I am just showing the dummy data. I am just writing the code to show the logic. So, I am not adding items to _sacnnedItems collection in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot initialize `_scannedItems` dictionary in TestCase. For future, you can debug test(and method code) like normal code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't add anything to _scannedItems, I suppose any discount on an empty basket will always results to zero...